# x86 Assembly on a Mac

Tags: xcode, macos, x86, assembly

Does anyone know of any good tools (I'm looking for IDEs) to write assembly on the Mac. Xcode is a little cumbersome to me.

Also, on the Intel Macs, can I use generic x86 asm?  Or is there a modified instruction set? Any information about post Intel.

Also: I know that on windows, asm can run in an emulated environment created by the OS to let the code think it's running on its own dedicated machine. Does OS X provide the same thing?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

After installing any version of Xcode targeting Intel-based Macs, you should be able to write assembly code.  Xcode is a suite of tools, only one of which is the IDE, so you don't have to use it if you don't want to.  (That said, if there are specific things you find clunky, please file a bug at [Apple's bug reporter](http://bugreport.apple.com/) - every bug goes to engineering.)  Furthermore, installing Xcode will install both the Netwide Assembler (NASM) and the GNU Assembler (GAS); that will let you use whatever assembly syntax you're most comfortable with.

You'll also want to take a look at the [Compiler & Debugging Guides](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010019), because those document the calling conventions used for the various architectures that Mac OS X runs on, as well as how the binary format and the loader work.  The IA-32 (x86-32) calling conventions in particular may be slightly different from what you're used to.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the system call interface on Mac OS X is different from what you might be used to on DOS/Windows, Linux, or the other BSD flavors.  System calls aren't considered a stable API on Mac OS X; instead, you always go through libSystem.  That will ensure you're writing code that's portable from one release of the OS to the next.

Finally, keep in mind that Mac OS X runs across a pretty wide array of hardware - everything from the 32-bit Core Single through the high-end quad-core Xeon.  By coding in assembly you might not be optimizing as much as you think; what's optimal on one machine may be pessimal on another.  Apple regularly measures its compilers and tunes their output with the "-Os" optimization flag to be decent across its line, and there are extensive vector/matrix-processing libraries that you can use to get high performance with hand-tuned CPU-specific implementations.

Going to assembly for fun is great.  Going to assembly for speed is not for the faint of heart these days.

Comment: Two people upvoted his sass and zero people actually fixed the link... it would be nice if Apple actually had old links redirect to new articles... I've found links to Apple docs linked from SO are almost always dead...

Comment: Archive.org version (latest version before it got chopped) http://web.archive.org/web/20090622125037/http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/CompilersDebuggers-date.html

Answer (score 30):

As stated before, don't use syscall. You can use standard C library calls though, but be aware that the stack MUST be 16 byte aligned per Apple's [IA32 function call ABI](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/LowLevelABI/130-IA-32_Function_Calling_Conventions/IA32.html).

If you don't align the stack, your program will crash in `__dyld_misaligned_stack_error` when you make a call into any of the libraries or frameworks.

The following snippet assembles and runs on my system:

```
; File: hello.asm
; Build: nasm -f macho hello.asm && gcc -o hello hello.o

SECTION .rodata
hello.msg db 'Hello, World!',0x0a,0x00

SECTION .text

extern _printf ; could also use _puts...
GLOBAL _main

; aligns esp to 16 bytes in preparation for calling a C library function
; arg is number of bytes to pad for function arguments, this should be a multiple of 16
; unless you are using push/pop to load args
%macro clib_prolog 1
    mov ebx, esp        ; remember current esp
    and esp, 0xFFFFFFF0 ; align to next 16 byte boundary (could be zero offset!)
    sub esp, 12         ; skip ahead 12 so we can store original esp
    push ebx            ; store esp (16 bytes aligned again)
    sub esp, %1         ; pad for arguments (make conditional?)
%endmacro

; arg must match most recent call to clib_prolog
%macro clib_epilog 1
    add esp, %1         ; remove arg padding
    pop ebx             ; get original esp
    mov esp, ebx        ; restore
%endmacro

_main:
    ; set up stack frame
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push ebx

    clib_prolog 16
    mov dword [esp], hello.msg
    call _printf
    ; can make more clib calls here...
    clib_epilog 16

    ; tear down stack frame
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    mov eax, 0          ; set return code
    ret
```

Comment: Can anyone tell me why running this example with "nasm -f macho hello.asm && gcc -arch i386 -e _main -lSystem -o hello hello.o && ./hello" gives "Bus error: 10" at the end of the output ?

Comment: Figured it out: I think there was a bug. The end of clib_prolog should sub %1 bytes in order to pad for arguments, and clib_epilog should add %1 bytes. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 10):

Recently I wanted to learn how to compile Intel x86 on Mac OS X:

#### For nasm:

```
-o hello.tmp - outfile
-f macho - specify format
Linux - elf or elf64
Mac OSX - macho
```

#### For ld:

```
-arch i386 - specify architecture (32 bit assembly)
-macosx_version_min 10.6 (Mac OSX - complains about default specification)
-no_pie (Mac OSX - removes ld warning)
-e main - specify main symbol name (Mac OSX - default is start)
-o hello.o - outfile
```

#### For Shell:

```
./hello.o - execution
```

#### One-liner:

```
nasm -o hello.tmp -f macho hello.s && ld -arch i386 -macosx_version_min 10.6 -no_pie -e _main -o hello.o hello.tmp && ./hello.o
```

Let me know if this helps!

I wrote how to do it on my blog here:

http://blog.burrowsapps.com/2013/07/how-to-compile-helloworld-in-intel-x86.html

For a more verbose explanation, I explained on my Github here:

https://github.com/jaredsburrows/Assembly

Answer (score 8):

Running assembly Code on Mac is just 3 steps away from you. It could be done using XCODE but better is to use NASM Command Line Tool.
For My Ease I have already installed Xcode, if you have Xcode installed its good.

But You can do it without XCode as well.

Just Follow:

1. First Install NASM using Homebrew `brew install nasm`
2. convert .asm file into Obj File using this command `nasm -f macho64 myFile.asm`
3. Run Obj File to see OutPut using command `ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0 -lSystem -o OutPutFile myFile.o && ./64`

Simple Text File named myFile.asm is written below for your convenience.

```
global start
section .text

start:
    mov     rax, 0x2000004 ; write
    mov     rdi, 1 ; stdout
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, msg.len
    syscall

    mov     rax, 0x2000001 ; exit
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall

section .data

msg:    db      "Assalam O Alaikum Dear", 10
.len:   equ     $ - msg
```

Comment: I have downloaded DosBox for MacOS and feeling the best way to run assembly language on MacOS.
Let me share some steps to do this.
1- Download DosBox.dmg for MAC and install
2- copy folder named Assembly to any place in your computer in my case i have copy assembly folder to desktop. (I have downloaded this folder from a website site let me share a git link to download in new thread)
3- run command "mount c: /users/akhzar/desktop/Assembly" in DosBOX then write c: and press enter.
4- Now you are in drive c to run Assembly Language Commands

Comment: 1- Now run .asm file using following command
c:\> nasm a.asm -o a.com -l a.lst
(this will create two files one is .lst and other is .com)

2- Now run AFD to see this in Debug Mode
c:\> afd a.com
(use f1,f2 function keys to run and the program till terminate)

3- To go back from debugger use the following command

quit

Comment: Download Assembly Language Folder from this link
https://github.com/akhzarna/AssemblyLanguageOnMac

Comment: if I use it with `-macosx_version_min 10.14.1`, Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executablesymbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64

Comment: @AkhzarNazir :Original question is a bit ambiguous in that it is not clear of what kind of assembly code development is meant. I believe that original question was about how to develop assembly code natively on Mac - using Mac toolchain and execute final outcome on Mac. You are showing how to develop assembly for DOS/Windows within emulated runtime running on Mac which is what I believe not what original question is about.

Answer (score 6):

> Also, on the Intel Macs, can I use generic x86 asm? or is there a modified instruction set? Any information about post Intel Mac assembly helps.

It's the same instruction set; it's the same chips.

Answer (score 1):

The features available to use are dependent on your processor. Apple uses the same Intel stuff as everybody else. So yes, generic x86 should be fine (assuming you're not  on a PPC :D).

As far as tools go, I think your best bet is a good text editor that 'understands' assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about finding a IDE to write/run/compile assembler on Mac. But, remember mac is UNIX. See http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html. A decent guide (though short) to running assembler via GCC on Linux. You can mimic this. Macs use Intel chips so you want to look at Intel syntax.