# How to print argv[0] in NASM?

Tags: macos, assembly, nasm, argv

I want to store `argv[0]` in a register and then print it, but I'm getting a segfault when I run my assembly program.

Trace:

```
$ nasm -f macho -o scriptname.o --prefix _ scriptname.asm
$ ld -o scriptname scriptname.o -arch i386 -lc -macosx_version_min 10.6 -e _start -no_pie
$ ./scriptname
Segmentation fault: 11
```

scriptname.asm:

```
[bits 32]

section .data

program: db "Program: %s", 0

section .text

global start
extern printf
extern exit

start:

; skip argc
add esp, 4

; ebx := argv[0]
pop ebx

push ebx
push program
call printf
add esp, 8

push 0
call exit
```

Specs:

- ld 64-134.9
- nasm 0.98.40
- Xcode 4.5
- Mac OS X 10.8.2
- MacBook Pro 2009

Comment: Are you sure the generated binary is 32bits only?

Comment: If it runs in 64bits, then the calling convention is not cdecl, but sys V.

Comment: @Macmade, Thanks for the info! I'll keep that in mind if I want to make 64 bit programs. The program *should* be only x86, since I specified `-arch i386` to `ld`. What happens when you try to build and run the same code on your machine?

Comment: Try 'lipo -info' on your binary to list the actual architectures.

Comment: `Non-fat file: scriptname is architecture: i386`

Comment: You've got an issue with the stack alignment, hence the segmentation fault.

Comment: @Macmade, could you rewrite the code so that it aligns the stack?

Comment: I don't know "-f macho". In my experience, if it were 64-bit you'd get a complaint about `push ebx`. I don't think you should have to do this, but try a `mov ebx, [ebx]` before the push. Newer vesions of Nasm  are available at http://www.nasm.us but I doubt it'll help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The segmentation fault comes from a **bad stack alignment** (`misaligned_stack_error`).
When you have such an issue, always **try running your program with GDB**. It will usually provide you with more information.

But to resume, as you are calling functions from the C library, the stack needs to be aligned on **16 bytes boundaries**.
This is a requirement for the **Mac OS X 32 bits ABI** (note this is also the case for the 64 bits ABI, which uses the SYS V calling convention).

So here's a working version of your program, that will print the executable name, as well as the number of CLI arguments (explanation is just after that):

```
[bits 32]

section .data

    hello db "Program name: %s (%i CLI args)", 10, 0

section .text

global start
extern _exit
extern _printf

start:

    ; Store 'argc' into EAX
    pop     eax

    ; Store 'argv' into EBX
    pop     ebx

    ; Align stack on a 16 bytes boundary,
    ; as we'll use C library functions
    mov     ebp,                esp
    and     esp,                0xFFFFFFF0

    ; Stack space for local variables
    ; A little more space than needed, but that will
    ; ensure the stack is still aligned
    sub     esp,                16

    ; Call 'printf': printf( hello, ebx, eax );
    mov     dword[ esp ],       hello
    mov     dword[ esp + 4 ],   ebx
    mov     dword[ esp + 8 ],   eax
    call   _printf

    ; Call 'exit': exit( 0 );
    mov     dword[ esp ],       0
    call   _exit
```

Compile it using:

```
nasm -f macho -o test.o test.asm
ld -o test test.o -arch i386 -lc -macosx_version_min 10.6
```

**Explanation:**

We first store `argc` and `argv` in some registers:

```
    pop     eax
    pop     ebx
```

And then we align the stack on a 16 bytes boundary:

```
    mov     ebp,                esp
    and     esp,                0xFFFFFFF0
```

You can do this only once, at the beginning of `start`, assuming you **keep the stack aligned**, when creating space for your local variables.

Then we create the necessary space for local variables, **ensuring the stack is kept aligned.**
Here, we only need room for 3 stack arguments, but we create space for 4, to keep the stack aligned.

```
    sub     esp,                16
```

You can then move values on that space, to prepare arguments for the call:

```
    mov     dword[ esp ],       hello
    mov     dword[ esp + 4 ],   ebx
    mov     dword[ esp + 8 ],   eax
```

Then simply call the C library function, and you'll be OK.

Note you may also find some useful informations in [this answer (x86 Assembly on a Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/357113/182676).

Comment: Even using these macros, I'm still getting alignment errors. Could you rewrite the original code for me?

Comment: @JaggedO'Neill You're correct. There's also performance reasons.

Comment: @mcandre Please see the edit : ) You should get it working now.