# Call C/C++ function from assembly (OSX Mavericks x64)

Tags: c++, c, assembly, posix, abi

This is a weird issue that I can't seem to find an answer to. This:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void show_number(int number) {
    cout << number << endl;   // Shows '10' as expected
}

int main() {
    cout << endl; // Remove this and it fails

    __asm {
        mov rdi, 10
        call show_number
    }
}
```

actually works fine, except when you remove the initial `cout << endl` (first line of `main`). When you remove it, the `cout` in `show_number` seems to cause a segfault for some reason.

What causes this?

(OSX Mavericks x64, but should work in linux as well I think)

Comment: can you show the contents of the registers before and after the call for both cases?

Comment: `asm volatile` doesn't build (?) - Apple Clang 2.1

Comment: @SteveCox I tried that, it's not really practical though.

Comment: What about `__asm volatile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mac OS X ABI requires a 16-bytes stack alignment, before calling a function.

If your code is working, you're simply lucky, and this explains why you're getting e segmentation fault when modifying previous sections of the code.

So you need to ensure the stack is aligned on a 16-byte boundary.
I already answered a similar question a few times ago:

[How to print argv[0] in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678230/how-to-print-argv0-in-nasm)

The interesting part is:

```
; Align stack on a 16 bytes boundary
mov     ebp,                esp
and     esp,                0xFFFFFFF0
```

Be sure to read the full answer, though...

Comment: I've heard that before, but I'm confused as to how to apply it. Can you show me a quick edit of my asm region to show how this should be done?

Comment: See the edit, and read carefully my answer in the post in mentioned.

Comment: Certainly appreciate the help, but something seems off. In fact, I can call functions all day long without having to worry about alignment, it only seems like `cout` has this problem. Any other function I call though seems to work fine.

Comment: With more experience I now understand what you mean. Marked as accepted, thanks.