# Mac assembly: segfault with libc exit

Tags: c, macos, assembly, x86-64, mach

I am diving into x86_64 assembly on macOS 10.12.

I am trying to call libc `exit()` function:

```
.section __TEXT,__text
.globl _main
_main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp
    movl $5, %edi
    callq _exit
```

And compile it with:

```
as exit2.s -o exit2.o
ld exit2.o -e _main -lc -o exit
```

The result is:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Why is it so?

Edit: the issue is in linking libc and calling conventions.

Comment: Try using your C compiler to link so you get all the necessary stuff linked in correctly.

Comment: @Jester I am using [this guide](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/12/02/writing-64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x/) as a reference.

Comment: From a glance, that guide has horrible things, I would not be surprised if this one didn't work either. Have you tried `gcc -o exit exit2.s` (or equivalent?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call C/C++ function from assembly (OSX Mavericks x64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136530/call-c-c-function-from-assembly-osx-mavericks-x64)

Comment: @Jester Yes, it works with `gcc`. Do I understand it right: `gcc` performs some under-the-hood linking magic? My goal was to understand what happens there.

Comment: Most probably a stack-alignment issue. Read the above question and answer.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678230/how-to-print-argv0-in-nasm

Comment: Yeah it could also be a stack alignment (although I would be surprised if `exit` needed anything aligned). You could try removing the `push %rbp` and see if it works that way. Also you can do `gcc -v -o exit exit2.s` to get it to print what commands it is running for you. Obviously best would be to run it in a debugger so you can actually examine the fault.

Comment: @Jester The macOS ABI requires stack alignment when calling a C function. Period. It does not depend on which function you call.

Comment: You don't initialize the libc, no wonder your program crashes.  Never ever use the libc without also linking through the C compiler so the libc initialization stub is linked in.

Comment: @Macmade It does depend whether you get a crash or not. Because it's not actively checking for alignment so you can get lucky if the function does not use aligned instructions.

Comment: @Jester If this guide is bad, do you know any decent getting-started tutorial?

Comment: @CorellianAle: Don't call your ELF entry point `_main` or `main` in a static executable.  CRT startup code hasn't run yet.  The usual convention is to call it `_start`.  (Note that OS X puts the CRT start code in the dynamic linker, so [the "entry point" in a dynamically-linked executable *is* the C `main` function, unlike in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801580/can-i-do-ret-instruction-from-code-at-start-in-macos-linux).  **So libc would be initialized if you linked with `gcc` instead of `ld` or `gcc -static -nostartfiles`**.)

Comment: I'm curious. When you link with LD do you get any warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@fuz is almost certainly correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48270676/mac-assembly-segfault-with-libc-exit#comment83525287_48270676): **you crash because you didn't initialize libc**.  There's probably a NULL pointer somewhere in the data structures that `exit(3)` checks before actually exiting.  e.g. it flushes `stdout` if needed, and it runs any functions registered with [`atexit(3)`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/3/atexit/).

If you don't want it to do all that work, then either make the `sys_exit` system call directly with a `syscall` instruction, or `call` the thin `_exit(2)` libc wrapper function for it.  (The basics of the situation will be the same as on Linux, because `exit(3)` vs. `_exit(2)` are standardized by POSIX: see [Syscall implementation of exit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903180/syscall-implementation-of-exit).

---

I think [the tutorial you're following](http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/12/02/writing-64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x/) mostly looks good, but perhaps some older version of OS X allowed libc functions (including `printf`?!?) to be used without calling any libc init functions.  Or else they didn't test their code after an edit to the build commands.  (Assuming they tested at all, maybe it was with dynamic linking, which would work.)

---

**OS X prefixes symbol names in assembly with an `_`, so use `call __exit`** (two underscores) to call `_exit()`.  (e.g. `call _printf` calls the C `printf` function).

`_exit(2)` *probably* won't crash if you call it without initializing libc, but **it's still a bad idea to call any libc functions without having called libc init functions first**.  Better to make the system call directly (see later in the tutorial), or even better, build it with `gcc hello_asm.S -o hello_asm` to make sure libc is initialized.  Then you can follow the rest of the tutorial, including the `printf`.

---

Don't call your Mach-O entry point `_main` or `main` in a static executable.  CRT startup code hasn't run yet.  The usual convention is to call it `_start` for the process entry point.

(Note that OS X puts the CRT start code in the dynamic linker, so [the "entry point" in a dynamically-linked executable *is* the C `main` function, unlike in Linux where dynamic executables can avoid the CRT startup code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47801580/can-i-do-ret-instruction-from-code-at-start-in-macos-linux).

libc would be initialized for you if you linked with `gcc exit2.o -o exit` instead of `ld`, which you're using to do the equivalent of `gcc -static -nostartfiles`.)

Comment: OS/X(MacOS) isn't ELF it is macho/macho64