# How to call C function from x86-64 Assembly on Mac (stack alignment and/or Makefile build issues)

Tags: c, assembly, macros, segmentation-fault, nasm

**tl;dr** I am getting a few different errors depending on how I try to call a C `_print` function from x86-64 assembly. I would like to get it printing by calling the C function, so I know I can call C functions, but I'm not sure how to do "stack alignment" to make that happen properly. The full source code for the system is included.

---

I tried following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255608/calling-c-functions-from-x86-assembly-language) instructions but I am getting this:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

My assembly looks like this:

```
section .text

global start
extern _print

start:
  mov rdi, msg
  jmp _print

section .data

msg: db  0xa, "  Hello StackOverflow!!!", 0xa, 0xa, 0
.len: equ $ - msg
```

My `print.c` function is like this:

```
#import <stdio.h>

extern
void
print(char *str) {
  puts("FOO");
  puts(str);
}
```

I am able to use the `print` function in C directly, so I know that works. So I should see `FOO` in the output but I just see something like this followed by an error:

```
Hello StackOverflow!!@���
```

I compiled the C project like this:

```
print:
  @clang -I . -dynamiclib \
    -O2 \
    -undefined dynamic_lookup \
    -o print.dylib print.c
.PHONY: print
```

And I compiled the asm project like this:

```
asm:
  @nasm -f macho64 main.asm
  @ld -macosx_version_min 10.13.0 \
    -lSystem -o main \
    -install_name print.dylib \
    main.o print.dylib
  @./main
.PHONY: asm
```

- [Call C/C++ function from assembly (OSX Mavericks x64)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136530/call-c-c-function-from-assembly-osx-mavericks-x64)
- [How to print argv[0] in NASM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678230/how-to-print-argv0-in-nasm)
- [x86 Assembly on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649/x86-assembly-on-a-mac/357113#357113)
- [Why does the Mac ABI require 16-byte stack alignment for x86-32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612443/why-does-the-mac-abi-require-16-byte-stack-alignment-for-x86-32)
- http://www.idryman.org/blog/2014/12/02/writing-64-bit-assembly-on-mac-os-x/
- http://nicolascormier.com/documentation/macosx-programming/MachORuntime.pdf
- http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/devel/assembly/MachORuntime.pdf
- http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/nasmtutorial/
- https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI

I don't understand how to apply this stack frame / alignment concept to the 64-bit architecture.

Tinkering around and I tried changing `start` to this. I have no idea why (don't understand how to apply the stack alignment):

```
start:
  push rbx
  mov rdi, msg
  call _print
  pop rbx
```

It ends up outputting this:

```
  Hello StackOverflow!!@���make: *** [asm] Error 109
```

Still no `FOO` from the print as well.

Comment: `int len = sizeof(str);` I think you mean `strlen(str)+2`.

Comment: Of course, you can do the whole thing more simply, and avoid the need for the extra array, with `printf("FOO%s\n", str);`

Comment: I'm trying my best to avoid the `printf` and `sprintf` functions because they do too much. Still have to remove that last little bit.

Comment: So then, `puts("FOO"); puts(str); puts("\n");`

Comment: Perfect, thanks going to do that! But beside the point :)

Comment: Well, yes and no; I think the segfault is because you made the `out` array too small and overran it.  And because of buffering, you also wouldn't see the FOO be output if your program crashes before the later `printf`s.  So fixing that may get you closer than you think.

Comment: Oh, `puts` has a trailing newline so maybe you want `fputs(..., stdout)` instead.

Comment: As for the macro issue, I would guess that nasm doesn't expand macro parameters within a token such as in `_%1`.  A glance at the manual suggests that `_ %+ %1` may work but I haven't tried it.

Comment: But I really don't see the point of your macro.  You're defining a "helper" function `print` whose only job is to call `_print`.  It doesn't align the stack correctly and it doesn't return properly.  Compared to just calling `_print` yourself, this just wastes cycles and complicates your program.

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few other problems with what you're trying to do.  You are making your assembler routine the entry point of the program, which means that the standard C library's startup code never gets to run.  As such, you can't expect that calls to C library functions, e.g. stdio, are going to work properly.  Another issue is that after your call to `_print` returns, execution just runs off the end of `start`.  You need to write code to invoke the `_exit(2)` system call or your program is going to die by segfault.

Comment: I have a lot of functions that will go through the macro, let's say a few hundred. I don't like the _prefix underscore and I can't figure out how to [get rid of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034852/adding-leading-underscores-to-assembly-symbols-with-gcc-on-win32/1035937#1035937) in clang, but I want to export the assembly library with `print` not `_print` so you can use it in another c or assembly project.

Comment: Running again a bunch of times it gives `Error 12, Error 16, Error 17, Error 18, Error 20, ... Error 21`. Well _that's_ helpful haha.

Comment: So, I think the first question to be resolved is: do you want the C library startup code to run, or not?  If no, you can keep your entry point called `start`, but you'll have to resign yourself to not being able to safely call any nontrivial C library functions, e.g. `fputs` or `printf`, and you'll have to do I/O yourself with lower level system calls like `write(2)`.  You'll also need to exit manually. But if yes, you should make your entry point be a label called `_main` and expect it to be called with C conventions, and you can exit your program by simply returning.

Comment: If I try to rename the function name in compiler output according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034852/adding-leading-underscores-to-assembly-symbols-with-gcc-on-win32/1035937#1035937), as in `extern func () asm ("FUNC");`, I get `error: invalid instruction mnemonic 'FUNC'`.

Comment: I want to use only system calls if possible so what you're saying sounds good, however low-level it can get.

Comment: `asm("FUNC")` is a gcc feature so I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't work with clang.

Comment: Any standard library symbol names will have a leading underscore, you can't avoid that.  (You could for libraries you create yourself, though).  But anyway, instead of a runtime wrapper (which should be a `jmp` tailcall, not another `call` + `ret` which breaks stack args and stack alignment), just use **`%define print _print`**  Or make your `lib` macro do `%define %1 _%1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes what about exporting the functions in the assembly project so you can use it in another assembly or c project. I don't want to have to use it there with underscores if at all possible.

Comment: @PeterCordes changing it to `start:
  mov rdi, msg
  jmp print` results in `Hello StackOverflow!!P���make: *** [asm] Error 30` It should show `FOO` I don't understand.

Comment: If you want to call it from C, you need the `_print` names because that's part of the platform name-mangling convention.  If you want to use it from another NASM project, you need `extern` declarations anyway, so you might as well have a NASM "header" file that you `%include` which uses extern and `%define` for each library function.  (Really I'd suggest just getting used to it: `_name` functions can be a handy reminder that the're written in C and use the C calling convention, while other names might be asm with a custom calling convention.)

Comment: @LancePollard /facepalm.  I meant change the `call` *inside the wrapper function* to `jmp`, to make it truly a transparent wrapper that forwards all its args without messing up the stack.  I think you still haven't realized that `call` at the bottom of that wrapper function will return *there*.  Think about what return address will be pushed by a `call` from different places.  But using `%define` is an even better alternative than calling to a `jmp` instruction anyway.

Comment: I updated the question based on the feedback, removed the macro stuff since it was unnecessary. Mainly I just want to be able to call a C function I made like that.

Comment: Your Makefile is basically defeating the purpose of dependencies.  Your print target should be `print.dylib: print.c`, and `asm` should be `main: main.asm print.dylib`.  Then you don't need a `.PHONY` because your rules accurately describe what you're building.  (And `make main` will rebuild the C library if it's out of date, too.)  You could break things down more (into `.o` dependencies) to allow `make -j` to build the library and run NASM in parallel.

Comment: Does it help if you `#include <stdio.h>` in your `print.c`?  As is, it compiles but with a warning about ```implicit declaration of function ‘puts’```, so you should probably fix that!  Also, on OS X, are you sure it's safe to call libc functions from `start`, not `main`? Or do dynamic-library hooks let libc run its init function before execution reaches the top of `start`, like on Linux? You're returning from `start` (by tail-calling a function that will eventually `ret`), not making an `_exit` system call or calling `exit` in libc, so maybe it's not the entry point at all? I don't have a Mac

Comment: Anyway, your code works for me on Linux, `gcc -O2 -shared lib.c -o libprint_lib.so`, assemble with `nasm -felf64 p.asm`, link with `gcc -nostartfiles p.o -L/tmp -lprint_lib` to create a dynamically linked executable.  (I had to change the source to `call print wrt ..plt` for it to link into a PIE executable.)  Runs with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp ./a.out` and prints both `FOO\n` and `\nHello...\n\n`, then segfaults after execution falls off the end of `start`.  So you're probably building it wrong.

Comment: What happens if you do `ld -macosx_version_min 10.7.0` instead of `ld -macosx_version_min 10.13.0`

Comment: @MichaelPetch it gives `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from`...

Comment: Are you using the code in your question or something else?

Comment: The makefile is the same, but I was using slightly evolving code debugging (c is large file). But copy-pasting the asm above gives `Segmentation fault: 11`.

Comment: I can understand you getting `Segmentation Fault` since you don't use an exit system call to exit your program after returning from `print` in function `start`. Did it print FOO and Hello World before faulting?

Comment: Going back to 10.13 and changing `start` to `_main` gives `Hello StackOverflow!!P���make: *** [...] Error 30`. I removed all includes/macros.

Comment: No it doesn't print anything on 10.7.

Comment: What version of `start` are you using. The one with `jmp` or the one with the `call` surrounded by push/pop?

Comment: The one with jmp.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with the `lldb` debugger?

Comment: And when you said it didn't print anything were you using 10.7.0 or 10.13.0?

Comment: No I didn't know of that. That might be good. With push/pop start and 10.7 it prints 
`
  Hello StackOverflow!!P���
make: *** [...] Segmentation fault: 11`. On 10.7 with jmp it doesn't print.

Comment: If you send me a copy of your program `main` to mpetch@gmail.com I may be able to look at it.