# Call printf produces segmentation fault, core dumped error in assembly compiled with gcc

Tags: assembly, gcc, segmentation-fault

I've never tought it will be the time to ask my first question here, but here I am.

I have to learn assembly as part of my University studies, and searching the internet didn't bring me an answer to my problem.
The problem is that I get segmentation fault core dumped when I try even this simple code:

```
.text                        

hello_str:                    
    .asciz "Hello, world!\n"                      

.global  main                      
main:
    
    movq %rsp, %rbp     
    movq $0, %rax
    movq hello_str, %rdi

    call printf
```

I use gcc -no-pie -o hello.o hello.s
and then ./hello.o
Commenting call printf makes it run, but without output(obviously).
The question is what am I doing wrong?
My pc is working on 64 bits has the Windows 10 OS but I use the Windows Subsystem for Linux to compile the program.

Comment: Even using $hello_str gives the same error

Comment: Probably a stack alignment or calling convention issue...

Comment: Make sure the first argument needs to be passed in rdi, and check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678230/how-to-print-argv0-in-nasm/12679627#12679627

Comment: yes, it does. I found out the problem and I will also put this as the answer. I needed to put: pushq %rbp at the beggining

Comment: `movq hello_str, %rdi` is a qword load.  Maybe you meant `movq $hello_str, %rdi` to pass the address?  (Or better, `lea hello_str(%rip), %rdi`).  Aligning the stack isn't sufficient to make this code work.  Also, without a `ret` after the call, this will obviously crash.

Comment: @Macmade: x86-64 System V does pass the first arg in RDI, IDK why you're linking a 32-bit question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I've mentioned already that even using $hello_str gives the same error, but yes you are right. I meant $hello_str

Comment: Well yeah, it makes sense that you need both things to be correct.  Either a bad pointer or stack misalignment will make printf crash.  Stuff like this matters.  Your self-answer to this question implies that adding `push %rbp` to the exact code in the question would make something that worked.  But that's obviously not the case, making it still not helpful for future readers to copy as an example.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, you are right. I modified my answer

Answer (score 0):

So I found out the answer. The thing is that I needed to put before everything this:
pushq %rbp
And modify hello_str to $hello_str

I don't know exactly what it does, but it seems to be working with it there.

Comment: As mentioned by Macmade this is likely due to stack alignment. The call to `main` leaves `rsp` pointing 8 bytes past a 16-byte boundary. The ABI requires you to change `rsp` by 8 to align it again before you make another call. Though saving and restoring `rbp` may also be needed anyway (the code calling `main` may need this).