# How do you program in assembly on OS X

Tags: macos, assembly, compilation, osx-lion

I have the latest version of OS X (Mountain Lion) and am trying to find a way to write and build programs in assembly language (Intel x86, 32 bit). Does a simple guide to set up an environment exist? I have been unable to find a simple way to do this after searching both stackoverflow and google.

Comment: What kind of environment are you looking for? The command line `as` already is a functional assembler, but I suspect you mean something more IDE like?

Comment: I thought OSX was 64 bit?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Yes, but you can run 32 bit applications on it.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649/x86-assembly-on-a-mac), and specifically Chris Hanson's answer may provide a starting point, although it refers to the GNU assembler, which I presume is superseded in the latest versions of Xcode.

Comment: @Monolo `Apple Inc version cctools-836, GNU assembler version 1.38` is what I get as `as` with the newest XCode installed on Mountain Lion. `nasm` is also still available.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I don't do assembler, so won't pretend to really know anything about it, but llvm seems to provide some support, too: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CompilerTools/Conceptual/LLVMCompilerOverview/

Comment: I've never done ASM on OS X, but on Linux and Windows, 64-bit ASM is much simpler.  I would strongly suggest skipping over antiquated technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/). Xcode is also available, but has been steadily moving away from being a general purpose IDE.